# PHP DateTime inclusive diff

Tags: php, datetime

I want to use the diff method of PHP DateTime to get the total number of days between two dates, inclusive of the start and end dates.

I've tried this:

```
 $start_date = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
 $end_date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');
 $diff = $end_date->diff($start_date)->format("%a");
```

but it returns **30**. I'm expecting 31.

How do I use the diff method to include the end dates?

Comment: `$diff = 1+ $end_date->diff($start_date)->format("%a");` don't thank me

Comment: *The difference between Feb. 1st and Feb. 1st is 1.* - Doesn't make a lot of sense. Just saying.

Comment: @deceze I see your point. Seems what I really want is the interval, not difference. The context is a datepicker to select an interval between two dates. I need to know the number of days selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
$end_date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');
$end_date->modify('+1 day'); //add 1 to include the end date
$diff = $end_date->diff($start_date)->format("%a");
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this method

```
$diff = $start_date ->diff($end_date ); 
echo $diff ->format('%y years %m months and %d days');
```